# Prove a set has measure 0

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set has measure $0$. Prove that the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \,x-y\in A\}$ also has measure zero.

I don't know how to start. Please help me or give me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Your set in $R^2$ is a shearing of $A\times R$, a set of measure $0$ in $R^2$.

Comment: I have searched the Luzin N property, but the given set is not the f(A).

Comment: @user363464: I think the given set is not a shearing of $ A\times R$.

Comment: Consider the shearing $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,y)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $B:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \,x-y\in A\right\}$ and $B_x:=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R} : \,x-y\in A\right\}$. By Fubini's theorem, 
$$\lambda_2\left(B\right)=\int_{\mathbb R}\lambda\left(B_x\right)\mathrm dx.$$
What is $\lambda\left(B_x\right)$?